# Has a Sweet Sixteen ever had all 4 top seeds in each region?

Tags: basketball, collegiate

The [2019 NCAA Men's Division I Basketball Tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_NCAA_Division_I_Men%27s_Basketball_Tournament) came close to having all of the top 4 seeds in each region make it to the Sweet Sixteen.  Only 2 teams lower than a 4-seed made it to the Sweet Sixteen - Auburn (5-seed) and Oregon (12-seed).

Was there ever a Sweet Sixteen that had all 4 top seeds from each region, or one that came closer than the 2019 season?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. [2009](https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/ncaab/2019/03/25/march-madness-ncaa-tournaments-chalk-first-weekend-sweet-16/3265225002/) was as close as 2019 in which two four seeds were joined by a 5-seed and a 12-seed in the Sweet 16.

> **For just the second time ever, the top three seeds in every single region 
>   advanced to the Sweet 16, and they were joined by two other No. 4
>   seeds.** Only Oregon (No. 12 in the South) and Auburn (No. 5 in the
>   Midwest) prevented the entire first weekend from going chalk.
>
> Seeds were first introduced to the NCAA tournament in 1979, and the
>   field expanded to 64 in 1985. Since then, **2009 is the only other year
>   that the top three seeds in every region advanced**. That year also
>   featured the lowest seed total – the sum of the remaining seeds in the
>   tournament – at 49.

Comment: Nice info about the seed total.  And this is the first time I've heard the term `chalk`.